# No targets in Prometheus at Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

Why are there no targets at my Prometheus? I did everything like in the Prometheus documentation. Also, I have pods with the label: "name=cadvisor".

I have the following configuration file:

```
# prometheus-config.yml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 5s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: "kubernetes-pods"
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: "pod"
            selectors:
              - role: "pod"
                label: "name=cadvisor"
```

[image: Prometheus screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on how you deploy Prometheus to the cluster
Kube-prometheus-stack ?
default chart ?

with kube-prometheus-stack it is very easy to deploy external configuration.

also using prometheus operator you can use podMonitor/serviceMonitor.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/14540)